# Recommended approach on back-end server to handle API keys?

Tags: javascript, server, backend, fetch-api

I'm building a website that has to request data from [Riot Developer Portal](https://developer.riotgames.com/). I've read through the doc and tried using `fetch()`.

```
fetch('https://na1.api.riotgames.com/lol/summoner/v4/summoners/by-name/Doublelift?api_key="KEY')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => console.log(data));
```

This resulted in getting CORS error, which I looked into. And learn that basically you can do this because your API key would be on the client-side which would be a security issue.

> *No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.**

I tried using mode: "no-cors" or "cors".

So I need to create a backend server, but I don't know how to do this. In searching around I found this guide : [AWS Guide to setting up server  API Gateway with Lamda](https://pastebin.com/LYsyfGgD) but the AWS interface has changed so I don't know how to follow this guide.

**My Main Question:**
***How do I learn backend server properly and be able to fix this issue?***

Comment: I'm afraid "how do I build a backend server" is far too broad a question for Stack Overflow. Fortunately, there are loads of libraries/frameworks to make it easy, so I would recommend simply picking your favourite backend language and googling for web frameworks in that language - you will likely find plenty to choose from!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

the easiest way to implement a backend (if you're a javascript developer) is through node.js & using the express.js framework. watch a youtube guide on creating rest apis with express/node.js

you will fetch() to your server, which will fetch() to Riot's API, then return the response to your font end. Cors is applied by the browser, that's why you need your server to make the request to Riot's API. and since its your server you can configure it to accept cors from your domain or IP address.

you can deploy your backend on heroku very easily. AWS API Gateway and Lambda is also a good option, but slightly more difficult for someone learning the ropes of backend.

Comment: You can improve this answer a lot by providing example code.